Does the Inverse Function Theorem Extend to Manifolds with Boundary?
I have been studying smooth manifolds and differential geometry, focusing on the Inverse Function Theorem (IFT), which is a fundamental result in this area. My question is: Can the statement of the Inverse Function Theorem be extended to manifolds with boundary?
Theorem (Inverse Function Theorem for Manifolds without Boundary):
Let $ M$ and $ N $ be two smooth manifolds of the same dimension, and let $ f: M \to N $ be a smooth map. If $ p \in M $ and $ df_p $ is invertible, then there exist neighborhoods $ U \subset M $ of $ p $ and $ V \subset N $ of $ f(p) $ such that $ f|_U: U \to V $ is a diffeomorphism.
Now, I would like to explore whether this holds when $ M $ has a boundary.
My Example:
Consider the inclusion map $ i: \mathbb{H}^n \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $, where $ M = \mathbb{H}^n = \{(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : x_n \geq 0\} $ and $ N = \mathbb{R}^n $. In this case, $ M $ has a non-empty boundary (the hyperplane $ x_n = 0 $).
At $ p \in M $, we compute the differential $ df_p = di_p = I: T_p \mathbb{H}^n \to T_p \mathbb{R}^n $, which is the identity map and therefore invertible (since $ T_p \mathbb{H}^n = T_p \mathbb{R}^n $).
However, the map $ f = i: \mathbb{H}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $ is not a local diffeomorphism at $ p \in \partial \mathbb{H}^n $, as it is not even a local homeomorphism, which is evident from the geometry near the boundary.
Question:
Does this counterexample demonstrate that the Inverse Function Theorem does not hold when $M $ has a boundary, or am I missing something in my reasoning?
